# Can't target applications in Adobe's ExtendScript Toolkit CC

Tags: javascript, adobe-illustrator, extendscript

The usual way of targeting applications is no longer functional for me, which is a known bug of the program:

[image: As stated in the readme file].

One solution that has worked for others is to include a #target directive in the code, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4027089/5476392).

However, when I try the same, I get an error message stating that the target application - in this case, "illustrator" - is

[image: undefined].

Without being able to properly target my application, the only way to develop and test my scripts is to manually navigate to them from within the application itself, rather running them from within the ExtendScript Toolkit, which is quite a nuisance.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Pending an ExendScript Toolkit solution: if you place your script into Illustrator's own `Scripts` folder (for me it's in "Presets\en_GB\Scripts"), you can call it up from the File > Scripts menu. And you have to restart Illy once for it to appear. (Also, pending Adobe *finally* adding a Scripts Panel, which InDesign has had from its very first version!)

Comment: There is a newer version of extend script out. I am running 4.5.5 have you tried the new version?

Comment: I'm using the latest version of all software.

Comment: What is the illustrator installation folder? Can you open Illustrator app without extendscript? Have you install it using the creative-cloud desktop app? Do you have license or it's cracked? What is the exact version of estk and illustrator?

Comment: Installation folder is default. Yes I can open illustrator without extendscript. Yes, all programs were installed with the desktop app. Yes, all software is licensed. Version of ESTK is 3.5 I believe. Version of Illustrator is 19.0.0.0 I think (I'm not on that particular computer at the moment).

Answer (score 3):

I just did some testing. This works on the latest Illustrator CC 2015.1

```
#target illustrator-19
```

When I did:

```
#target illustrator
```

It was trying to launch illustrator CS4 which was the last CS version i had before switching to CC. Looks like they changed that up a bit.

Comment: I am on OS X  by the way.

Comment: I tried that earlier and got the same error as before. Thanks, though.

Comment: Works great on my machine.. Guess I'll have to bow out at this point. Good luck.